# Use PC broadband connection and distribute the bandwidth with wifi lan card

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I am using win 8. My PC is connected to the internet through broadband using a PPPOE connection system. I have a USB LAN card. Now I am wondering if there is any way to make my USB LAN as USB router and share my PC Broadband PPPOE connection with other device like my mobile phone etc over wifi.

I know this can be done easily with a wifi router but I am just curious if there is any way do do this like above mentioned way.

So is there any Idea??

Comment: its not the same, I am connecting through wire and want to share internet with usb wireless lan card

Comment: I'm confused.  In that question, the user has a wired internet connection and wants to share it using his computer's wifi card.  Isn't that the same thing that you want?